# MATLAB: Show colorbar of a grayscale image in a figure containing a RGB image

Tags: matlab, rgb, colorbar

Suppose we have two images:

1) RGB Image:

```
% initialize RGB image:
rgbIm = zeros(100, 100, 3); 
rgbIm(20:80, 20:80, 1) = 1;
```

2) Grayscale Image:

```
% initialize grayscale image:
grayIm = zeros(100);
grayIm(20:80, 20:80) = 1;
```

Lets show both of them:

```
figure, imshow(rgbIm),  colormap('jet'), colorbar;
figure, imshow(grayIm), colormap('jet'), colorbar;
```

As we can see, the *colorbar* in the 2nd figure (i.e. grayscale image) makes total sense. On the other hand I can't really understand the information given by the colormap in the 1st figure.

What I would like to achieve is to **display the colorbar of the grayscale image in the figure corresponding to the RGB image**.

It might seem that this does not make sense but this is just a very minimal example that I just made up to show what I would like to do in a larger project.

Any thoughts?

Thanks a lot :)

**EDIT1:** Allow me to explain why I would need this

Suppose I compute some physiological parameters one MRI slice in certain regions of interest, yielding something like this:

[image: parametric image]

Now I want to superimpose these parameters on top of the original slice, and I create one RGB image to achieve this:

[image: superimposition on the original image]

The colormap does not make sense, and this is why I would like to display the colormap corresponding to the parametric image in the RGB image (i.e. the superimposition image).

Any ideas?

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Answering my own question so I can hopefully help someone in the future)

I just accomplished what I intended, with the help of the above [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16403186/1714410) and a post from [Steve Eddins' blog](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2009/02/18/image-overlay-using-transparency/).
Here's how:

```
baseImage = baseImage/(max(baseImage(:))); % normalize base (anatomical) image
rgbSlice  = baseImage(:,:,[1 1 1]);        % converting to RGB (ignore colormaps)
imshow(parameterROIImage, []);             % show parametric image
colormap('jet');                           % apply colormap
hold on;
h = imshow(rgbSlice);                      % superimpose anatomical image
set(h, 'AlphaData', ~bwROIlocations);      % make pixels in the ROI transparent
colorbar;
```

where `parameterROIImage` is:

[image]

`bwROIlocations` is the logical matrix containing the ROI pixels:

[image]

Final result:

[image]

Thanks for the help Shai.

Comment: How did you generate the different coloured pixels in your first image? Can you explain please? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I still think what you are asking does not make sense.
Let me explain:
What is `colorbar`? Colorbar is a representation of a function (mapping) from gray-level (scalar) to color. Using `jet`, in your example, you map the 0 to dark blue and 1 to red.
By asking for a `colorbar` for an RGB image, you are actually asking for a mapping from RGB triplet to RGB color -- this mapping is the identity mapping! you do not need a `colorbar` to see this mapping, each pixel represent it!

#### EDIT

After seeing the edited question, I revise my answer a bit:
Since both MRI signal and whatever physiological parameters you computed makes no sense in RGB space, you have two 1D mappings:
1. MRI signal at each voxel to gray level ("gray" colormap)
2. Physiological measure at each voxel to "jet" color

What I usually do in this cases is convert the 2D MRI slice into RGB gray image by simply replicate it along the third dimension

```
rgbSlice = twoDSlice(:,:,[1 1 1]);
```

Now show the images on top of each other

```
figure;
imshow( rgbSlice );
hold on;
h = imshow( physiologicalParams );
colormap jet;
set(h, 'AlphaData', .5 ); 
colorbar
```

You might need to play with the color mapping of the axes using `caxis` or `clim` to get it right.

Comment: Edited the original post in order to explain the motivation for the original post. Hope it now makes sense and I would be glad to hear your thoughts on this. Thanks.