# Generate heat map on top of an image using matlab

Tags: matlab, heatmap

[image: Here is the scatter plot and the image -]I want to generate heat map on a certain image. I have a m by 2 matrix 'templeCoords' (representing the pixel points of the image). I was using the following lines to keep the image on.

```
C=Imread('nwntemplemap.png');

%% Display the picture
figure, imshow(C)
hold on;
HeatMap(templeCoords);
```

It opens 2 different windows - one with the image I loaded and the other one is the heat map I guess.

Unfortunately was not able to manage it since working with heat map for the first time. Can anyone help please?

Added Question: Is it even doable to draw heat maps with the available data I mentioned?

The picture on top is the scatter plot of the points and the image -

Comment: Looking at the documentation for HeatMap, I'm not sure feeding it pixel points is the right way to go.  Also, I can't figure out what you want the final display to look like.  It seems like putting the heat map on top of the image is going to obscure the image.  Can you give an example of what you want?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I want it to something like this map here - http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/WOA09_sea-surf_SAL_AYool.png

Comment: possible duplicate of [MATLAB: Show colorbar of a grayscale image in a figure containing a RGB image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16403014/matlab-show-colorbar-of-a-grayscale-image-in-a-figure-containing-a-rgb-image)

Comment: Thanks Shai. But not sure where to allocate my matrix.

Answer (score 3):

I would make the heatmap and overlay your image(is it a maze?) on top of that. and make your image kind of transparent. 
check this out on how to do it.
http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2009/02/18/image-overlay-using-transparency/

To use the HeatMap function in matlab,you need to feed in the 2-D histogram(i.e. how many observations at a specific coordinate) for your templeCoords.
try this
http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2010/01/22/advanced-making-a-2d-or-3d-histogram-to-visualize-data-density/

this

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29709-function-to-make-a-2d-histogram

or this

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14205-2d-histogram